# I need help to improve this R code to extract specific cell from each sheet in xlxs

Tags: r, excel, for-loop, optimization

I have these codes below that extract the first column and third-row cell from each sheet of an excel file and then combine them into one data frame. I have three files each has 196,97 and 39 sheets respected. The code works, but it is taking too long.

Can you suggest a better method that reduces the run time
[This link i](https://fultonk12-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/tanp_fultonschools_org/EQFEKIrS5HpDt8rjsbvCGwUBX7bjCbvkjNFMKKhJb-cimQ?e=VLEbXz)s a sample original excel file. I have modified it to ask this question.

My original code is

```
Team3Q<-getSheetNames("reportTeam_3_FultonCountySchools.xlsx")

#using For Loop to extract particular cells from each of the sheets in the Excel spreadsheet.
#I need to get the content of the first column and third row of each sheet.
for (j in 1:length(Team3Q)){ 
  tmp<-read.xlsx("reportTeam_3_FultonCountySchools.xlsx", 
                 sheet = j,
                 startRow = 3,
                 colNames = FALSE,
                 rowNames = FALSE,
                 detectDates = FALSE,
                 skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
                 skipEmptyCols = TRUE,
                 rows = c(3,4),
                 cols = c(1:2),
                 check.names = FALSE,
                 namedRegion = NULL,
                 na.strings = "NA",
                 fillMergedCells = FALSE
  )   
  if (j==1) Team3Questions<-tmp else Team3Questions<-rbind(Team3Questions,tmp)   #happend to previous
}
Team3<- cbind(Team3QNumber,Team3Questions)
```

The end result from this process is data frame with two column where each sheet number and “question number” corresponds to the “questions” extracted from the 1column 3 row of each sheet.

Look  like this:

```
Question-Number  Question
3.2.1           Question 1
3.2.2           Question 2
3.3.1           Question 3
3.3.2           Question 4
3.3.3           Question 5
3.4.1           Question 6
3.4.2           Question 7
3.4.3           Question 8
3.4.4           Question 9
3.4.5           Question 10
```

Comment: You're growing objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)

Comment: Thank you. They are a great article. I am learning more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use lapply() instead. This will give you a list, with one item per sheet. Then rbind the list items together with do.call():

```
Team3list <- lapply(Team3Q, function(x) read.xlsx("reportTeam_3_FultonCountySchools.xlsx",
                                     sheet=x, #function-x is here
                                     startRow = 3,
                                     colNames = FALSE,
                                     rowNames = FALSE,
                                     detectDates = FALSE,
                                     skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
                                     skipEmptyCols = TRUE,
                                     rows = c(3,4),
                                     cols = c(1:2),
                                     check.names = FALSE,
                                     namedRegion = NULL,
                                     na.strings = "NA",
                                     fillMergedCells = FALSE)
       )


Team3 <- do.call(rbind, Team3list)
```

edit: I just realized that if you use sapply instead of lapply, you will get these 3.2.1, 3.2.2, ... values instead of 1,2,3,4,... You only need to gsub() them afterwards to get rid of this ".X1" at the end.

```
Team3list1 <- sapply(...)
Team3 <- do.call(rbind, Team3list1)
rownames(Team3) <- rownames(gsub(".X1$","", Team3))
```